# How to integrate google mobile analytics in web apps

Tags: google-analytics, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-analytics

Can anyone help me to integrate google mobile analytics in a web app? I know how to integrate [google mobile analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) in native android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong documentation.
See here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/?hl=en

When you actually implement code, ask a question... and also, ths is not specific to Worklight, but to any web app.